# broken package libmysqlclient20 causing error installing Rmagick

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, rmagick, error-code, dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient20_5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04_i386.deb (--unpack):
```

Trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient20/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libmysqlclient20:i386
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9)

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmysqlclient20_5.7.21-1ubuntu16.04_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Can you share the commands you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the file as follows

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient20/changelog.Debian.gz /usr/share/doc/libmysqlclient20/changelog.Debian.gz.backup
```

and then run `apt-get -f install` to solve this problem.